# session.Query is not getting the updated record from database

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using session.query,first time its return latest database records and we populate on grid after editing on fields we save on database and then we again execute this query then it is not getting the updated record from database. the fields has updated in database but not getting updated record.

My NHibernate query is given below

```
List<FiscalPeriod> lstPeriods = new List<FiscalPeriod>();
    using (var tr = session.BeginTransaction())
    {

        try
        {
            List<TSCFiscalPeriod> lstFiscalPeriods = session.Query<TSCFiscalPeriod>().ToList();

            if (lstFiscalPeriods != null && lstFiscalPeriods.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var period in lstFiscalPeriods)
                {
                    FiscalPeriod objPeriod = new FiscalPeriod();
                    objPeriod.Period = period.Id.FPeriod;
                    objPeriod.Name = "Period " + objPeriod.Period;
                    objPeriod.CompanyID = period.Id.FCompanyID;
                    objPeriod.Year = period.Id.FFiscalYear;
                    objPeriod.Begin = period.FBeginDate;
                    objPeriod.End = period.FEndDate;
                    objPeriod.OpenAP = FOpenAP(period.FOpen);
                    objPeriod.OpenGL = FOpenGL(period.FOpen);
                    objPeriod.SCFiscalPeriod = period;
                    objPeriod.IsExisting = true;
                    lstPeriods.Add(objPeriod);
                }
            }
            tr.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lstPeriods = null;
            CusException cex = new CusException(ex);
            cex.Write();
        }
        return lstPeriods;
    }
```

Is there any refresh method or something i am doing wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.thanks

Comment: I dont know much about NHibernate but from what I have read the session is like a UnitOfWork. In examples I have seen a new Session is fetched and Closed for each transaction... are you re-using the same session? http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#quickstart-playingwithcats

Comment: yes we are using same session.We had already remove "using (var tr = session.BeginTransaction())" and check the functionality but same thing is happening

Comment: Is that not your problem, the fact you are using the same session...
Have you tried closing the session with each commit of a transaction, like in the link I provided?
Again I am not so hot on NHibernate, having not used it in about a year.

Comment: after `lstPeriods.Add(objPeriod)` are you missing a `session.Save(objPeriod);` that is you want to tell NH to persist this upon a commit (unless its an identity column then it will do it earlier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you are using `session.clear()` or `session.flush()` after save the session.

Answer (score 2):

Nhibernate session is a static initializer.
Sometimes session is not able to refresh values.

So You have to flush and clear the session

```
session.flush();
session.clear();
```